# What's the meaning of the separator?

Tags: sheet-music

I'm learning the Bach's French suite using this [edition](http://petruccilibrary.ca/linkhandler.php?path=/imglnks/caimg/1/1a/IMSLP492403-PMLP5771-bachfranzoesischesuitenscore.pdf). Throughout there is a small separator (small vertical line) and I cannot guess its meaning. It definitely have something to do with this [question](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/70009/what-is-the-meaning-of-this-small-vertical-line), but it doesn't explain whole of them, and if it is just a change in a repetitive pattern, not all of them are noted. Here is an example (see the vertical line between the first and the second eighth-note.). Here it is indeed a change in a repetitive pattern.

[image]

If it is indeed the meaning, what exactly qualify for a change in a repetitive pattern? Do you use these marking when studying/playing the piece?

Comment: There is a footnote on the first page of the music (page 3) which explains what they mean!

Comment: "Do you use these marking when studying/playing the piece?" No, because they are just the personal view of some editor. Bach didn't write them.

Comment: Oh! Thanks. I guess one should not start directly with the second suite :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As  @alephzero commented, the marks are explained at the bottom of the page.  The editor felt the structure of the piece was worth marking out, and he exhorts you to  consider them in your phrasing.

You should consider his opinions, and follow them if you see fit.  They're not stupid opinions.

[image]